# Accessing parts of list elements in Python

Tags: list, indexing, slice

I have a list like this: `mylist=[17,747,757,767,777,787]`.

How can I access the **first two digits** of `mylist[1]`, so that I obtain `74`?

How could I generalize the process, regardless of the `length` of a given list element?

Comment: `mylist[1]/10` This will divide 747 and 10 which since they are both integers will return an integer (no decimal place). so you will get 74

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with integers, but you could convert to a string:

```
int(str(mylist[1])[:2])
```